# Strange intermittent lag phenomenon over wireless LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, lag

I'm connecting to computer Y on my wireless LAN at home. Y is a newly-assembled machine running Kubuntu 14.04; it's wireless adapter is "Realtek RTL8192CE PCIe (rev 01)". Between other machines on the WLAN I get reasonable behavior, no strange delays etc (specifically, typing in a terminal over an SSH connection is responsive). However, when SSHing to Y, the establishing the connection takes longer than expected, and later on there are occasional delays between the time a key was pressed and the time it shows up on screen. 'lag', if you will. Except that it is inconsistent, and sometimes the lag goes away for a few seconds and resumes again.

I'm not seeing something particularly interesting in the logs, but I may well be overlooking a hint somewhere.

My suspicion is that this has something to do with the network stack, maybe the wireless driver. What can I do to pinpoint the problem?

Notes:

- Seeing timeouts also when using CIFS/SMB.
- Another machine that is very close-by doesn't exhibit the same behavior when I connect to it.
- Load average is very low, the machine is mostly idle.
- Just tried connecting machine Y with Ethernet to one of my other machines - and that makes the problem go away (!). I still want to connect via WLAN though.

---

Contents of `/proc/lan/wireless`:

```
Inter-| sta-|   Quality        |   Discarded packets               | Missed | WE
 face | tus | link level noise |  nwid  crypt   frag  retry   misc | beacon | 22
 wlan0: 0000   46.  -64.  -256        0      0      0      0   4313        0
```

link ranges from 34 to 58, level from -246 to -50, noise is -256 all the time. Discarded packets figure is for 7.5 hours of uptime.

top 4 powertop entries:

```
     Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
   1.4 ms/s     101.2        Process        kwin -session 10146e4d
   3.7 ms/s      33.6        Process        /usr/lib/firefox/firef
 640.7 µs/s      32.4        Process        /usr/bin/java -Dosgi.r
  48.8 µs/s      21.7        kWork          ieee80211_iface_work
```

Comment: There are some other machines that use the same wireless channel, example Microwaves, TV signal repeaters, etc. You can start by checking the wireless signal with: 
# watch -n 1 cat /proc/net/wireless

Comment: @cfreire: Added results of that to the question.

Comment: Apparently you have a poor WI-fi connection (link 34 / level -256) good values (link 70 / level -30). Noise -256 indicates no outside interference.
Try, if possible move equipment to increase these values

Comment: @cfreire: Playing with the antennae and moving the box around improves the values - but behavior remains the same.

Comment: OK. In another direction. Is your loadvg (first value) above the number of cores?
# watch -n -1 cat /proc/loadavg

Comment: Can you try the conection with another link, ex. ethernet?

Comment: @cfreire: Ethernet make the problem go away. Load average is very small (0.02), I don't do much with the box right now - just hooked it up...

Comment: If possible verify the power saving for the wireless link 
# powertop 
and  
# iwlist wlan0 power

Comment: On #powertop (3TAB - STATS) see if wifi card is using all the power at 100% try disabe with #sudo iw wlan0 set power_save off